# Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libicui18n.52.dylib in with restricted binary

Tags: macos, composer-php, osx-elcapitan, intl

When using composer to install project dependencies on my development machine Mac running El Capitan I get the following error. I have intl installed but it appears to be trying to load another extension. It works fine if I have CSRUTIL disabled.

Reason: unsafe use of relative rpath libicui18n.52.dylib in /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so with restricted binary in Unknown on line 0

Is there a quick change I can make or install to fix this while csrutil is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, seems intl is installed, but the link to the lib is somehow messed up.
You could try to fix it by using a symlink. I believe the lib is somewhere around in `/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/<version>/...`.

Other solutions coming to mind are simply re-installing intl via brew or pecl.

Reinstall intl using brew

```
$ brew update
$ brew search icu             # ok, the correct name is 'icu4c'
$ brew install icu4c
```

or Reinstall intl using PECL:

```
$ sudo pecl update-channels
$ sudo pecl install intl
```

Comment: I will test this tonight or tomorrow and see what happens